# How to get the XY coordinates of the segments in a rule?

Tags: inkscape, export, effects, data-visualisation, xml

I have a curved line and because I wanted it to be divided in segments of equal distances, I used a Rule effect. (The image is in Spanish, but I hope you know what I mean with Rule - I don't know if that is the correct English name)

[image: Rule window]

I divided that line into 80 segments, and as you sure know, those divisions are not nodes. You can see the line and its segments here:

[image]

How can I get the XY coordinates of all the segments where they cross the line?

I was using the XML editor and found a huge amount of numbers. I was playing with no success.

Is there any possibility to export them in .csv, .txt or whatever other format easily? It would be very important for my scientific work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After several tries, I finally found the Inkscape extension called ExportXY. I simply installed that extension and it worked perfectly. For anybody who might be interested in this issue, I wrote a post in me blog concercing the steps to succed obtaining the coordinates (it's in Spanish, but as there is a single picture, I hope it may be useful).
https://vivaelsoftwarelibre.wordpress.com/2015/10/19/obtener-las-coordenadas-xy-de-los-nodos-en-inkscape/